# New column based on the combination of other columns

Tags: python, pyspark

So I have a pyspark dataframe such as:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| null | 3 |

I want a new column C that takes value from A, except when A is null, that it should take the value from B.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 |
| null | 3 | 3 |

How should I do it? These are the packages I am using just in case:

```
#Instalacion de paquetes
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from functools import reduce #para merge dataframes en loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce` function

```
df = df.withColumn('C', coalesce(col('A'), col('B')))
```